# Curses in the gemara

Tags: curse

Should we be worried about the various curses of the chachamim of the gemara? Does this effect practil halacha  in any way?
For example, one who bows toward a rainbow, one who prays mincha close to sunset or one who renegs on a deal. All recieve a curse.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please provide examples of curses. If you mean the sharp lines, see Chavos Yair 152, printed in the back of Seffer Chafetz Chaim.

Comment: @user6591 for those that don’t have access or can’t read Hebrew so well, care to summarize?

Answer (score 1):

Yes though it might depend.

For example buying and selling items there is a curse of "[mi she'parah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A2)" that if one side (usually the seller) backs out of the sale after it has been confirmed (ie: money transferred), they are subject to a curse. Perhaps it needs a Court to make it take effect, or perhaps Hashem will enforce it anyway. I suppose that might depend on your outlook.